# sum function returns inconsistent values when used with slicing

Tags: python, list, sum, slice

```
lst=[2,5]
sum(lst)
```

This returns 7 as expected

```
lst[0]
```

This returns 2 as expected

```
lst[1]
```

This returns 5 as expected

```
sum(lst[0:-1])
```

why does this return 2 instead of 7??

Comment: You're surprised about `sum([2])` being `2`?

Answer (score 0):

This is as expected as `lst[0:-1]` selects everything from the first element, up to one before the last element:

```
lst[0:-1]
>>> [2]
```